# Are squad tactics on topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

I would like to ask about a military concept developed around 1337 but used to day. Politics.SE rightfully told me off, would it be OK here? MartialArts.SE sounds like a worse fit.

Comment: Its tough to answer this without more specifics. I know we had a [well-received question on the French Column](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/2263/whats-the-advantage-of-the-infantry-column-formation-in-the-napoleonic-wars), so that was clearly on-topic. But if someone wanted to ask about using that formation *today*, that would probably be off-topic.

Comment: I know its can be a disappointment, but not every possible question the human mind can conceive has an appropriate SE site to ask it on.

Comment: @T.E.D. indeed. Thanks for the time! The linked question uses 'did' while mine is composed mostly of 'is defined as'. Definitely not topical here.

Comment: Sometimes theoretical questions can be made into good questions for the WorldBuilding SE site.

Comment: For a moment, I thought you were asking about 1337sp33k. But I agree with @T.E.D. here. Questions need to be asked in a historical context. For example, posting a picture of an unlabeled weapon you saw in a museum and asking what kind of troops carried it is probably fine. Asking about how to use it today to defend against a burglar would not be, and asking about how to incorporate it into a role-playing game would also not be.